# Did Drona please Lord Shiva with a shower of arrows?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, reference-request, dronacharya

I heard this description of Drona:

> He that pleased Lord Shiva using a shower of arrows

Is this true? Please give scriptural references.

Comment: Could you share where exactly in Mahabharat you read this? Some context would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I have not heard this in the Mahabharath.It was in a cinema,whose protagonist was likened to Dronacharya.Its BGM carried this description,so I wanted to know whether this is true or not.

Comment: @CDR -I am deeply regretful for completely nonsensical post. Thanks for vigilance and deleting my completely wrong answer. Instead of Drona my answer was about how Arjun pleased Shiva. Perhaps the story was stuck in my memory. I checked further about Dronacharya pleading Shiva but could not find at short notice. But will maintain a search. Sometimes I see how my mind works through my mistakes. Namaskar.

Comment: @ajitdas - thanks for understanding that it wasn't actually an answer- I hope you eventually find the correct reference, and will be sure to upvote when you do.

Answer (score 1):

Deepest apologies for nonsensical wrong answer before. This information is the closest I could get. **Please do not upvote** as the correct precise  answer would have "a shower of arrows"! However Drona did please Lord Shiva with his archery skills. The legend of Tapkeshwar Mahadev also mentions that both father and son did tapas to Mahadev in this cave, near Dehra Dun.

Again this not the answer containing shower of arrows. However -Drona of the Mahabharata was one of the greatest archers of his era. He was the Guru of both Pandavas and Kauravas. It is believed that Dronacharya did penance for 12 years in a cave near Dehradun in Uttarakhand. The cave is today famous as the Tapkeshwar Temple.

It is said that Shiva appeared before Drona in the cave. He was pleased with the supreme skills of Dronacharya in archery and blessed him.

Several years later, Ashwathama, son of Dronacharya, did penance in the cave standing on one foot. Shiva is believed to have appeared before him and blessed him with great skills in archery.

Today one can see the sculpture of Guru Drona on the entrance of the cave temple.